# How is this trig identity equal?

Tags: trigonometry

I do not understand how this is equal.

$$
{cos\theta(cos\theta-1)\over 1-cos\theta} = -cos\theta
$$

What simplification step am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that: $cos(x) - 1 = -(1 -cos(x))$.

Comment: thank you, I feel like I have a long ways to go to understand math...

Answer (score 0):

$${\cos\theta(\cos\theta-1)\over 1-\cos\theta} = -\cos\theta $$
$$\iff \cos\theta(\cos\theta-1)=-\cos\theta(1-\cos\theta)$$
$$\iff \cos^2\theta - \cos\theta = \cos^2\theta - \cos\theta $$